# Ignore [JsonIgnore] attribute on properties when receiving POST/PUT body of entity

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I'm creating a WebAPI to do CRUD actions on entities. For my entities, in some endpoints, I don't return all of its properties for the sake of bandwidth and performance on my front end.

To achieve this I use a `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on my Entity class, and when I want the entire class's info to be returned I use a custom `ContractResolver`.

Here's an exemple of a class: (baseEntity simply has an id field)

```cs
public class Product : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Label { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public float Price { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

and here's an example of the endpoint that causes me problems:

```cs
        [Route("add")]
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Add([FromBody] T paramEntity)
        {
            if (_entityService.Add(paramEntity))
            {
                return Content(convertObjectToJson(paramEntity), jsonContentType);
            }
            else
            {
                return StatusCode(500);
            }
        }
```

where `T` is `Product`

The problem here is that the `JsonIgnore` attributes are applied, so if I try to POST a request with values in `Description` for instance, that field is totally ignored.

I found a workaround by making two Entity classes:

- `ProductParent` has no `JsonIgnore` attributes and has all the initial properties of `Product`;
- `Product` still has them as seen above;
- `Product` inherits from `ProductParent`;
- `ProductParent` is what is used as the parameter type for my POST request, as seen below, where `U` is `ProductParent`:

```cs
[Route("add")]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Add([FromBody] U paramEntity)
{
    T entityToAdd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(paramEntity));
    var a = 1;
    if (_entityService.Add(entityToAdd))
    {
        return Content(convertObjectToJson(entityToAdd), jsonContentType);
    }
    else
    {
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

So while this kind of works it's unclean and could potentially stop working as soon as I move on to more complex types. Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: Look in to [DTO objects and AutoMapper](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=dto+objects+and+automapper). You're almost there already. I always called `Deserialize(Serialize(object))` a "poor-man's" automapper. Might as well go all in and do it the right way if you are going to use this pattern over and over.

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate of [Can I optionally turn off the JsonIgnore attribute at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37371786/3744182) and [Ignore `[JsonIgnore]` Attribute on Serialization / Deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37954376/3744182), agree?  DTOs + Automapper is also a valid solution.